# Formatting issue when creating page header in rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to learn Rmarkdown, but there is something that's quite elusive. I am trying to put my name at the top of every page of the PDF I print, however I also get the various headers from the text in the markdown file in the header, and it often overlaps and makes everything unreadable. I learned the basics from another thread on here, but still struggling. I only want my name in the header. I tried to modify it like what you see below, but then I don't get anything at all. This is my YAML:

```
---
title: "Something"
author: "something"
date: "42 42 42"
output: pdf_document
includes:
in_header: {My name}
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
---
```

Anyone who could write it so that I get only my name at the top of the page? Also, the onehalfspacing is the same as setting spacing to 1.5 in word right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a conceptual problem: The things you put in `includes: in_header:` in the yaml are the files included in the preamble of your tex document, similar to what you have in `header-includes:`. This is not in any way related to the headline of your document.

If you like to change this, have a look at the `fancyhdr` latex package

Please also note that the syntax for multiline `header-includes:` is wrong in your example. You need to prefix each line with `-`

```
---
title: "Something"
author: "something"
date: "42 42 42"
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \onehalfspacing
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \fancyhead[c]{your name}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
---

test

\newpage

test
```

Comment: i tried this, but the issue still remains, because some of the subheaders ## overlap over my name in the middle. Otherwise it looks good thanks :)

Comment: @Aite97 Can you make a [mre] that shows which problems you face?